# CoreData delete single object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode6

I'd like to delete an entry in the entity `Person` at the attribute `name` which matches with the value `Test`.

For example I saved an entry into core data like this: `object.setValue("Test", forKey: "markedCell")`. Now I want to find out if the entry `"Test"` is saved in the attribute `markedCell` and which indexPath it has. I tried the following one:

`var request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
 request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"markedCell = %@", "Test")
 var results : [NSManagedObject] = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as [NSManagedObject]`

Now I know if the entry `"Test"` exists but don't know which indexPath it has (I can only delete an entry if I know which indexPath it has right?). Currently I want to delete the entry `"Test"` (don't wanna set it to `""`).

My CoreData model:

[image: I want to delete <code>"Test"</code> from <code>markedCell</code>]

I want to delete `"Test"` from `markedCell`.

Does someone of you guys know how to do this in Swift ?

Creating a cell (`cellForRowAtIndexPath`):

```
//Get task
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
    var taskString:NSString?
    taskString = object.valueForKey("name") as? String
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("name") as? String

    println(object.valueForKey("name") as? String)

    //Set accessory type
    var request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"markedCell = %@", taskString!)
    var results : [NSManagedObject] = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as [NSManagedObject]
    if (results.count > 0) {
        //Element exists
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        println("Cell isn't marked")
    }
    else {
        //Doesn't exist
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
        println("Cell is marked")
    }
```

Crash:

[image]

[image]

I hope this pic helps to understand my question better. The link of the image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5g4yeoedg0xjjv/Stackoverflow_Question.png?dl=0

Answer (score 6):

> I can only delete an entry if I know which indexPath it has right?

This is wrong. A Core Data object does not have an index path.
(A *fetched results controller* manages Core Data objects for display
in a table view and then you have index paths, but that is completely
irrelevant here.)

Just fetch the object or the objects that you want to delete and delete 
them:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"markedCell = %@", "Test")
if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as? [NSManagedObject] {

    // Delete _all_ objects:
    for object in results {
        context.deleteObject(object)
    }

    // Or delete first object:
    if results.count > 0 {
        context.deleteObject(results[0])
    }

} else {
    // ... fetch failed, report error
}
```

Comment: Ok. So if I delete the first object it's the object `Test` and if I delete all objects markedCell is empty?

Comment: @horst: The fetch request fetches *all* objects with "markedCell == Test" (there could be many). If you *know* that there is only one matching object then it does not matter, otherwise you have to choose if you want to delete *one* or *all* matching objects.

Comment: Ok. Now `"Test"` is also deleted in `name`. I just want to delete it in `markedCell` (I updated my question with an image).

Comment: @horst: I don't understand what you mean. The above code deletes the object (or all objects) for which "markedCell == Test". It deletes the object(s) with all its attributes.

Comment: I stored `"Test"` in `name` and in `markedCell`. But I only want to delete `"Test"` in `markedCell`. In `name` `"Test"` it should be remain.

Comment: So you just want to set the "markedCell" attribute to nil? Is the attribute defined as "Optional" in the Core Data model inspector? Then you can do `object.setValue(nil, forKey: "markedCell")`  instead of `context.deleteObject(object)`.

Comment: No, if I run `object.setValue(nil, forKey: "markedCell")` I get an crash at creating a new cell / reloading tableView (see updated question). But if I close the app and relaunch it all works till I run `object.setValue(nil, forKey: "markedCell")` again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76926/discussion-between-horst-and-martin-r).

Comment: I updated my question with an image which describes my problem very detailed. I hope it helps to understand my question.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3:

```
       if let dataAppDelegatde = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {


                let mngdCntxt = dataAppDelegatde.persistentContainer.viewContext

                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ItemCart")

                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemId = %i", Int(currentItemID)!)
                print(currentItemID)

                fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
                do{
                    let result = try mngdCntxt.fetch(fetchRequest)

                    print(result.count)

                    if result.count > 0{
                        for object in result {
                            print(object)
                            mngdCntxt.delete(object as! NSManagedObject)
                        }
                    }
                }catch{

                }
            }
```